# Loading a pandas Dataframe into a sql database with Django

Tags: mysql, django, pandas

I describe the outcome of a strategy by numerous rows. Each row contains a symbol (describing an asset), a timestamp (think of a backtest) and a price + weight.
Before a strategy runs I delete all previous results from this particular strategy (I have many strategies). I then loop over all symbols and all times.

```
    # delete all previous data written by this strategy
    StrategyRow.objects.filter(strategy=strategy).delete()

    for symbol in symbols.keys():
        s = symbols[symbol]
        for t in portfolio.prices.index:
            p = prices[symbol][t]
            w = weights[symbol][t]

            row = StrategyRow.objects.create(strategy=strategy, symbol=s, time=t)

            if not math.isnan(p):
                row.price = p

            if not math.isnan(w):
                row.weight = w

            row.save()
```

This works but is very, very slow. Is there a chance to achive the same with write_frame from pandas? Or maybe using faster raw sql?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the first thing you should try is the raw SQL route (more on that in a bit)
But I think it's because of calling `row.save()` on many objects, that operation is known to be slow.

I'd look into `StrategyRow.objects.bulk_create()` first, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

The difference is you pass it a list of your `StrategyRow` model, instead of calling `.save()` on individual instances. It's pretty straightforward, bundle up a few rows then create them in batches, maybe try 10, 20, a 100 etc at a time, your database configs can also help find the optimum batch size. (e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Back to your idea of raw SQL, that would make a difference, if e.g. the Python code that creates the `StrategyRow` instances is slow (e.g. `StrategyRow.objects.create()`), but still I believe the key is to batch insert them instead of running N queries